# Estimating a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm trying to get an estimate for a distribution of values centred around a particular point. I have approximately 10^5 data points with a centre point of 15 with the values normally distributed. 99% of the data points will be found in the range of 12.5 and 17.5. How do I go about constructing this?

Answer (score 0):

99% corresponds to standard deviation of $2.576 \sigma$

and your mean value is $\mu = 15$.

Now you can simply enter those values in the formula for the probability density of the normal distribution.